# Make intro.js tooltip force to the right and make page scroll

Tags: javascript, intro.js

When you add a large tooltip in intro.js, it calculates whether it has space to put the tooltip on the top, bottom, left, right by doing the following:

```
/*
* auto determine position 
*/

// Check for space below
if (targetElementRect.bottom + tooltipHeight + tooltipHeight > windowSize.height) {
  _removeEntry(possiblePositions, "bottom");
}

// Check for space above
if (targetElementRect.top - tooltipHeight < 0) {
  _removeEntry(possiblePositions, "top");
}

// Check for space to the right
if (targetElementRect.right + tooltipWidth > windowSize.width) {
  _removeEntry(possiblePositions, "right");
}

// Check for space to the left
if (targetElementRect.left - tooltipWidth < 0) {
  _removeEntry(possiblePositions, "left");
}
```

It then decides to put the tooltip floating on top of the element as such [image]

Is there a way I can force it to make the tooltip go below the element and make the page scrollable?(dynamically change page height) (even after the actual original body has concluded)

Comment: Can you share full working example codes

Answer (score 0):

**UX tooltip definition** is a *absolute/fixed positioned element appearing near the cursor when hovering an UI item* ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip)).
IMHO you are using the wrong element type to accomplish a simple task usually done hiding/showing elements in you current scaffolding.
From the mock I desume you are already in a modal window, in that modal place your tooltip html and show/hide as a simple html object so you can retain the box model and document flow you need as the browser will do the calculation for you.